# How to create this procedural texture without using Noise Texture?

Tags: shaders, shader-nodes

Hi is it possible to create this procedural texture shader below without using the Noise Texture node? There is a bug when running blender 3.1 on windows 7 (if you are interested you can see it in the closed thread [Procedural Textures Working Perfectly but Bump Map is Pink](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/258524/procedural-textures-working-perfectly-but-bump-map-is-pink)) so i'm looking for a workaround trying to produce this same texture but without using a noise texture. Is this possible?

[image]

Comment: Well, because Windows 7 is not supported by the official Blender since version 2.93, you could try 2.90 or below to do that with the noise

Comment: yeah i know. but i like the latest version and unfortunately i only have windows 7 XD

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could try and fake it with overlaid, warped wave textures:

[image: Waves]

EDIT: If you're up for stretching, as moonboots suggested, I would recommend using a Voronoi Texture - Distance output. I would also recommend still warping the vectors slightly with a (non-detailed) distorted (wobbly) wave texture to get that "bent overlap" that is in your example image:

[image: Warp2]

Comment: wow cool amazing ! thank you soo much!

Comment: Hey, no problem. I'm sure there are simpler ways - that's just what came to me first. If I find anything better, i'll post it here.

Comment: that would be awesome :D

Answer (score 6):

You could also use this kind of setup (here with a *Musgrave*), stretch it on an axis, increase the node's *Detail* value to make it a bit more chaotic, create several needles in the *ColorRamp* to have some color variations:

[image]

Comment: wow cool thank you for sharing! <3